# How to use react context with nested mobx stores?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, react-context

I have two stores: `formStore` and `profileStore`

`FormStore`

```
export class ProfileFormStore {
    @observable editing = false;
    profileStore = new ProfileStore(this.roleId);
    originalValue?: ApiModel | null;

    @action.bound
    startEdit() {
        // this.originalValue = this.profileStore.toJson();  
/*  if uncomment above, next error thrown
    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at initializeInstance (mobx.module.js:391)
    at ProfileStore.get (mobx.module.js:381)
    at ProfileStore.get
*/
        this.editing = true;
    }
}
```

`ProfileStore`

```
export class ProfileStore {
    @observable userProfile: ApiModel = {
        userProfile: {
            newsAndUpdates: false,
            email: "",
            phone: "",
            lastName: "",
            firstName: "",
        },
    };

    @observable email = "";

    @action.bound
    fetch() {
        // this.fromJson(this.actions.fetch());
        console.log("start");
        this.email = "qwe";
        console.log("end");
    }

    @computed
    toJson(): ApiModel {
        return {
            userProfile: {
                firstName: this.userProfile.userProfile.firstName,
                lastName: this.userProfile.userProfile.lastName,
                phone: this.userProfile.userProfile.phone,
                email: this.userProfile.userProfile.email,
                newsAndUpdates: this.userProfile.userProfile.newsAndUpdates,
            },
        };
    }
}
```

And I want to use contexts

```
const formStore = new ProfileFormStore();
export const profileFormContext = React.createContext({
    formStore,
    profileStore: formStore.profileStore,
});

export const useProfileContext = () => React.useContext(profileFormContext);
```

And there are two components: `form` and `formControl`

```
const controls = {
    admin: (<><ProfileName /><Email /></>),
    user: (<><ProfileName /></>)
};
export const Form = () => {
    const { formStore, profileStore } = useProfileContext();
    // this.fromJson(this.actions.fetch()); // if uncomment throws 'Missing option for computed get'

    return <form>(controls.admin)</form>
}

export const ProfileName = () => {
    const { formStore, profileStore } = useProfileContext();
    formStore.startEdit(); // check form store, when assigning from profileStore get overflow error

    return formStore.editing ? <input value='test' /> : <label>Test</label>
}
```

So there are two kinds of errors:

1. When accessing `observables` from `ProfileStore` that is part of `FormStore`
2. When updating `observables` in `ProfileStore` that is part of `FormStore`

the `FormStore` working well

both stores injecting via `React.useContext` have followed these example https://mobx-react.js.org/recipes-context , however their stores are not nested. I made them nested, beacuse I wanted to get access to `profileStore` from `formStore`

What do these errors mean? How to fix them?

Comment: I'm not sure if its a good idea to use MobX with react's context, maybe try a different approach, unless you have a reason why you're doing it like that

Comment: @Teebo here https://mobx-react.js.org/recipes-inject `inject` mentioned as obselete, and I decided to give a try https://mobx-react.js.org/recipes-context as for me a context approach looks a better variant.

Comment: sorry I did not know about the "Kids don't do drugs", well I am not updated, I guess I cannot suggest anything at the moment

Comment: Computed "toJson" will not be triggered automatically unless your property of  "userProfile" named "userProfile" is also observable. Currently any changes in all "firstName, lastName, etc." will not trigger any actions.

Comment: @AntoanElenkov From the https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observable.html, `If value is an object without prototype, all its current properties will be made observable.`. I thought, it should apply recursively. BTW from the question, when triggering `toJson` manually I get the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error

Comment: @Nikita, about the observing - It's my bad, in your  case the observable is in computed prop, so it will work. Deep observing does not work if you try to observe it manually with mobx.observe. In this case you can use this solution - https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils#deepobserve 

About you issue for "maximum call stack exceeded" - you are missing "get" in front of computed
`get @computed toJson()`

Comment: @Nikita, I swapped  'get' & 'computed' unintentionally. It should be - `@computed get toJson()` .

Comment: @Nikita There is little to no justification regarding inject being "obsolete". It's just the opinion of the person who wrote that article. Inject is just a different approach that works quite well.

Comment: @Kev you right, I see two benefits from hookd. 1. No need to worry about provider. 2. type checked store injections

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not the answer :) But the solution I have used

```
export class ProfileStore {
   @observable editing;
   @observablt userProfile: UserProfile;
   ...
}
```

That's all - instead of using two stores, now there is one store, I happy that solution is working. I assume that error was that I forgot to write `get` at `toJson`. If in future I encounter same error and understand why it happened. I will try not to forget to update this answer.